# nodejs package for parsing excel formula DATEDIF in months?

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, excel-formula

looking for nodejs package that can read and process formula excel
datedif in months

im currently using
handsontable/RuleJS
https://handsontable.github.io/ruleJS/

but there is no datedif in month

i need a tool because the 
excel formula might be complex

from the current package i can do this in days

'IF(DAYS("6/6/2019","1/1/2019") >= 30,

now i need in months

Answer (score 0):

if you have access to just the fields then [`moment`](https://momentjs.com/) may work (`npm i moment`):

```js
var moment = require('moment');

// 'IF(DAYS("6/6/2019","1/1/2019") >= 30,
var result = moment('6/6/2019').add(1, 'months').isAfter(moment('1/1/2019'));
```